# Python logging config file modules and packages

Tags: python, logging, python-2.6, syslog

I am tearing my hair out.

I need a syslog handler.

I found [this](https://github.com/luismartingil/per.scripts/tree/master/python_syslog):
at a [StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968669/how-to-configure-logging-to-syslog-in-python/17688092#17688092) and found the approach works just fine standalone, communicates as it should with this system's syslog.

However, I can't figure out how to refer to it in my logging config file.  I am using Python 2.6.6 so dict config is not available to me.  I have to use file configuration.  According to docs the class name has to be either relative to logging or a full specification from the python path.

Here is the section of my config file:

```
[handler_syslog]
class=logext.HDSysLogHandler
level=WARN
formatter=timestamp
args=(7, )
```

logext is a package located one level deeper than my main.

It contains 3 python files and compiled files:

```
[logext]$ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-x---. 2 sc1478 dev 4096 Apr 25 11:50 .
drwxr-x---. 3 sc1478 dev 4096 Apr 25 11:50 ..
-rw-r-----. 1 sc1478 dev  243 Apr 25 11:50 HDSysLogHandler.py
-rw-r-----. 1 sc1478 dev  630 Apr 25 11:50 HDSysLogHandler.pyc
-rw-r-----. 1 sc1478 dev    2 Apr 25 11:50 __init__.py
-rw-r-----. 1 sc1478 dev  132 Apr 25 11:50 __init__.pyc
-rw-r-----. 1 sc1478 dev 2426 Apr 25 11:50 syslog_bridge.py
-rw-r-----. 1 sc1478 dev 2386 Apr 25 11:50 syslog_bridge.pyc
```

**init**.py is blank, just to make a package.

syslog.bridge.py is basically the file referred to above, with a small change to the constructor to make it more flexible and work with Python 2.6

```
class SysLogLibHandler(logging.Handler):
    ...
    def __init__(self, identifier, n):
        try:
            syslog.openlog(identifier, syslog.LOG_PID, self.FACILITY[n])
        except Exception , err:
            print err
            raise

        # We got it
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
```

finally HDSysLogHandler.py is as follows:

```
from syslog_bridge import SysLogLibHandler

class HDSysLogHandler(SysLogLibHandler):

    def __init__(self, local_facility):
        SysLogLibHandler.__init__(self, "hdaudio", local_facility)
```

The relevant section of the main module is:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import logext
...
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

When my main app is run, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 23, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/config.py", line 84, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/config.py", line 162, in _install_handlers
    h = klass(*args)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What is this trying to tell me?  WHAT module is not callable?  Who's trying to "call it"?

What is the RIGHT way to locate a home-brewed logging handler and specify it in a logging configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are seeing this error because

```
class=logext.HDSysLogHandler
```

specifies the class to be `logext.HDSysLogHandler`, which is a module, not a class. Instead try

```
class=logext.HDSysLogHandler.HDSysLogHandler
```

since this specifies the `HDSysLogHandler` class which is inside the `logext.HDSysLogHandler` module.

Comment: Thanks!  I love python except when I hate it.  :-)

Comment: and what was confusing me was the example of class=handlers.SysLogHandler.  In that case handlers is a module containing several classes, one of which is SysLogHandler whereas in my case the module contains one class of the same name.  No wonder I sometimes hate python.

Answer (score 1):

You shall start with platform specific documentation first :-)

Python 2.6 is providing [SysLogHandler](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html#syslog-handler)

If you like using dict configured logging configuration, you may use [logutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logutils/0.3.3) package, which provides [dictionary based configuration](http://pythonhosted.org//logutils/dictconfig.html) usable in Python 2.6.

I used in `logutils` in Python 2.6 a lot and was very happy with it. Later move to Python 2.7 was very easy.

Comment: you set me on the right path with logutils get logging working on py2.6