# Python 2.7 erroneously aggregating syslog messages with TCP, works fine with UDP

Tags: python, logging, tcp, udp, syslog

Using the Python 2.7.15rc1 that comes with Linux Mint 19.1, I am syslog'ing some data to rsyslog 8.32.0-1ubuntu4.  Doing so over TCP erroneously catenates multiple log messages into a single line in /var/log/syslog, while UDP correctly does not do this aggregation.

I want to use TCP instead of UDP for reliability, but I need the non-catenated output.

If I change a single line in my program from:

```
socktype = socket.SOCK_DGRAM
```

...to:

```
socktype = socket.SOCK_STREAM
```

...then things start catenating weirdly.  The one line is the only code change necessary to replicate the problem from known-good code.

This is how I'm getting the logging handler:

```
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=address, socktype=socktype)
```

The log messages in the good case (with UDP) look like (for EG) :

```
Jun 11 15:59:25 2019-06-11 15: 59:25,870|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading xgb_factory
Jun 11 15:59:25 2019-06-11 15: 59:25,871|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading lgb_factory
Jun 11 15:59:25 2019-06-11 15: 59:25,871|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading rf_factory
Jun 11 15:59:39 2019-06-11 15: 59:39,161|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading xgb_factory
Jun 11 15:59:39 2019-06-11 15: 59:39,161|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading lgb_factory
Jun 11 15:59:39 2019-06-11 15: 59:39,162|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading rf_factory
```

The log messages in the bad case (with TCP) look like (for EG) :

```
Jun 11 11:55:04 2019-06-11 11: 53:43,139|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading xgb_factory#000<14>2019-06-11 11:53:43,140|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading lgb_factory#000<14>2019-06-11 11:53:43,141|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading rf_factory#000<14>2019-06-11 11:53:57,842|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading xgb_factory#000<14>2019-06-11 11:53:57,843|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading lgb_factory#000<14>2019-06-11 11:53:57,843|_|INFO|_|dstromberg-inspiron-5570|_|domain.classifier.factories.classifier_academy|_|classifier_academy.py|_|load|_|132|_|loading rf_factory
```

The timestamp always has that spurious space (ASCII 32, after the hour in "2019-06-11 11: 53:43,139") in it in the TCP case, and multiple messages have been catenated into a single message.  The messages appear to be joined with something like: "#000<14>".  The #000 part is consistent, but the numeric portion, 14 in this case, changes from incidence to incidence.  It's always a smallish integer though.

Is this a bug in the SyslogHandler?  Is it a known issue? Does anyone know a fix, other than switching to UDP?

The only even slightly unusual thing I'm doing (other than syslog over TCP) is adding a filter to add a (docker) hostname.  That just looks like:

```
class ContainerFilter(logging.Filter):
    """This is a filter that just adds the container name (hostname)."""

    def __init__(self, name='', container_id=None):
        """Initialize."""
        super(ContainerFilter, self).__init__(name)
        self.container_id = container_id

    def filter(self, record):
        """Set record's metric and container_id attributes, if available."""
        record.container = self.container_id
        return True

filter_ = ContainerFilter(container_id=_DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID)
handler.addFilter(filter_)
```

I think it's happening too much to be a Nagle thing.

With regard to TCP versus UDP - I like the reliability of TCP, and I like it that when it's not working, there's an exception instead of just dropping messages.

Also: I know Python 2.x is going to be unsupported soon, but this particular code is going to be on 2.x a while longer yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SysLogHandler messages grouped on one line on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950147/sysloghandler-messages-grouped-on-one-line-on-remote-server)

Comment: The duplicate link also links to a Python bug issue that is marked as *not a bug*, sadly.

Comment: This looks kind of like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041697/pythons-sysloghandler-and-tcp .  Sadly, I think inheriting from SysLogHandler and overriding the emit method is kind of ugly.  I believe I'm have to use UDP.

Comment: The msg + '\n' suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041697/pythons-sysloghandler-and-tcp sounded really promising. Sadly it didn't work for me.

Comment: Try the alternative `msg = str(len(msg)) + ' ' + msg` given in the comment to the question there. This puts the length of the message then a space at the start of the message.

Comment: I'm guessing that length needs to be for the entire message, not just one part of the message.  I'd probably have to hack my SysLogHandler.  It's probably there to avoid Nagle and fragmentation.