# Python 2.7: setlogmask(0) not disabling syslog

Tags: python, python-2.7, syslog

I'm a Python newbie, and the following code wrote the following messages to /var/log/syslog

```
May  8 22:14:22.531833 almach <info>./test.txt: HELLO 01
May  8 22:14:22.531853 almach <info>./test.txt: HELLO 02
May  8 22:14:22.531860 almach <info>./test.txt: HELLO 03
```

So, why

1. Messages were written to /var/log/syslog and not ./test.txt?
2. setlogmask(0) was ineffective, and message "HELLO 02" was written to syslog?

Also, I tested the code in a Linux machine that had demon rsyslogd running, and it might have affected my code somehow.

```
from syslog import syslog, setlogmask, LOG_INFO, openlog

openlog('./test.txt')

syslog(LOG_INFO, "HELLO 01")

setlogmask(0)
syslog(LOG_INFO, "HELLO 02")

setlogmask(255)
syslog(LOG_INFO, "HELLO 03")
```

Comment: You cannot `setlogmask(0)`. The mask must be a bitwise combination of the [symbolic constants](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/syslog.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `LOG_MASK(0)` to avoid writing `HELLO 02` and remember previous value of mask to restore it before writing `HELLO 03`:

```
from syslog import syslog, setlogmask, LOG_INFO, LOG_MASK, openlog

openlog('./test.txt')

syslog(LOG_INFO, "HELLO 01")

mask = setlogmask(LOG_MASK(0))
syslog(LOG_INFO, "HELLO 02")

setlogmask(mask)
syslog(LOG_INFO, "HELLO 03")
```

Result in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May  9 01:49:39 sanyash-ub16 ./test.txt: HELLO 01
May  9 01:49:39 sanyash-ub16 ./test.txt: HELLO 03
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`syslog.openlog`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html#syslog.openlog) manual:

> The optional ident keyword argument is a string which is prepended to every message, and defaults to `sys.argv[0]` with leading path components stripped

To save logs in a separate file, use `logging.handlers.SysLogHandler`: [How to configure logging to syslog in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968669/how-to-configure-logging-to-syslog-in-python)