# Log to rsyslog facility from a python script

Tags: python-3.x, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have this in my `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
local0.*     /var/log/local.log
```

And I have a simple python script which reads from standard input and is supposed to send to `local0`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, syslog

syslog.openlog(ident="MY_SCRIPT", facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL0)

for line in sys.stdin:
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_WARNING, f"Message\n\n")
```

But it does not work. `rsyslog` does not see the messages as comming to `local0`

Only when I change to `*.*` does rsyslog see it:

```
*.*     /var/log/local.log
```

I assume I don't properly configure the facility in my python script.

How can I specify I want to log to `local0` ?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @jdaz - I am using Debian.

Comment: Try @boatcoder's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968669/how-to-configure-logging-to-syslog-in-python

Comment: @400theCat your code seems to be working fine for me . have you restarted the rsyslog after making changes ? ```systemctl restart rsyslog```

Comment: also i think you missed sending the actual commandline to the log file ```syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_WARNING, f"Message\n\n")``` should be ```syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_WARNING, f"Message {line}\n\n")```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rsyslog and local*:**

[Rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/) have the facilities `local0` to `local7` that are "custom" unused facilities that syslog provides for the user. If a developer create an application and wants to make it log to syslog, or if you want to redirect the output of anything to syslog (for example, Apache logs), you can choose to send it to any of the `local#` facilities. Then, you can use `/etc/syslog.conf` (or `/etc/rsyslog.conf`) to save the logs being sent to that `local#` to a file, or to send it to a remote server ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90842/what-is-the-local6-and-all-other-local-facilities-in-syslog)).

**Config:**

Under `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
local0.*     /var/log/local.log
```

This is correct and it assign the log file `/var/log/local.log` to apps that log to local0. As an other example `kern.=warn -/var/log/kernel/warnings.log` can be used to  log kernel warnings.

**Python application/script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, syslog

syslog.openlog(ident="MY_SCRIPT", facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL0)

for line in sys.stdin:
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_WARNING, f"Message {line}\n\n")
```

The initial code does work, and as pointed in the comments [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968669/how-to-configure-logging-to-syslog-in-python) can be used as an alternative and `{line}` variable have been added as suggested by @apoorva-kamath...

The important side here is on the **communication between the Python script and Rsyslog**.

Also as pointed on the command try is to reload rsyslog `systemctl restart rsyslog`; you can as well check the Rsyslog config with `rsyslogd -N1` and check if rsyslog is working correctly with:

```
sudo cat /var/log/messages | grep rsyslog
```

Depending on the Python script running context, communications to Rsyslog may fail, further details on your config are needed otherwise you can try (from the script's context):

```
logger -p local0.error "TroubleshootingTest"
```

And finally check the data transmission with:

```
sudo netstat -taupn | grep syslog
```

**Documentations:**

More details about [Python syslog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/syslog.html), [troubleshooting Rsyslog](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/Success_Center/loggly/Content/admin/troubleshooting-rsyslog.htm) and [Rsyslog facility](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/s1-basic_configuration_of_rsyslog)